# Argument Lookup in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

Running into an issue with gcc with c++14. When compiling the code below I get an error

```
"call of overloaded ‘make_unique(std::__cxx11::string)’ is ambiguous"
```

However if I remove the local definition of make_unique I also get an error:

```
"‘make_unique’ was not declared in this scope"
```

It seems like it should be impossible to get both of these errors as either the std::make_unique is pulled in due to ADL or it is not. Is this just an issue with gcc or is there something else going on?

For reference subbing make_unique for a non-template std function (such as stoi) gets rid of the "not declared in this scope" error which leads me to believe it is an issue with gcc.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
}   

struct A
{
    A(std::string a){ }
};  

int main()
{
    auto a = make_unique<A>(std::string());
}
```

Comment: FWIW, clang and MSVS2017 also reject the code for the same reason.

Comment: Strange... I thought ADL didn't apply to calls with explicit template arguments?

Comment: See [P0389R0](http://wg21.link/p0389r0).

Comment: @ildjarn `make_unique<A>(std::string());` still has a template argument that's not explicitly specified. The argument's type.

Comment: It doesn't get fun until you realize that a dummy, never defined `template <class>
void make_unique();` works as well ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug.

Without your local template definition,

```
make_unique<A>(std::string());
```

we don't have template definition of `make_unique` available and we have so

```
(make_unique < A) > (std::string());
```

With your definition, we have template definition and so, we can use regular ADL.